# error: The method 'configure' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseMessaging' in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wrote a code some time ago, now when I'm using it again, it shows me an error saying that `configure` isn't defined. Can someone edit this code, so it can be used in latest version of flutter? I tried changing some syntax bit can't convert the code.

Code-

```
_initFirebaseMessaging() {
    firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('AppPushs onMessage : $message');
        _showNotification(message);
        return;
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: Platform.isIOS ? null : myBackgroundMessageHandler,
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('AppPushs onResume : $message');
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, message['data']['action']);

        return;
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('AppPushs onLaunch : $message');
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, message['data']['action']);

        return;
      },
    );
    // firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
    // const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
    firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
      sound: true,
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
    );
  }
```

Comment: That is removed in breaking changes in new package versions. you can find new functions here https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage

Answer (score 4):

I think you are using the old method. Here is the new method:

My firebase_messaging package version is 10.0.1.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      showNotification(notification);
});

FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print("onMessageOpenedApp: $message");
});

FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage((RemoteMessage message) {
      print("onBackgroundMessage: $message");
});
```

Comment: `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage((RemoteMessage message) async {
    print("onBackgroundMessage: $message");
  });`

add async keyword if getting an error.

Comment: FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print("onMessageOpenedApp: $message");
}); not working . how to solve this issue.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72610335/fcm-push-notification-click-not-working-in-flutter